# ImmutableJS - Dealing with list of objects?

Tags: immutable.js

I'm learning to use ImmutableJS but I'm a little confused. I looked at the documentation and I see there are Maps for objects and Lists for arrays.

So I build an object like:
`sampleTodo = Immutable.Map({text: 'Testing 1 2 3', status: 'Open'})`

And then do: `list = Immutable.List().push(sampleTodo)`

Not sure if this is right. If it is, I get stuck when I have an index and have to return a modified `List`.

For example, if index is 0, I do:

`list.get(index)`

and get

`Object {size: 1, _root: ArrayMapNode, __ownerID: undefined, __hash: undefined, __altered: false}`

So, I don't see how I can set the status of the `Map` object to `status: "Complete"` by going through the `List`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a viable solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29655323/3281384

```
list = list.update(
  list.findIndex(function(item) { 
    return item.get("name") === "third"; 
  }), function(item) {
    return item.set("count", 4);
  }
);
```

Or, in my case,:

```
list = list.update(
  index, function(todo) {
    return todo.set('status', 'Complete');
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

`list = list.setIn([index, 'status'], 'Complete')`

The key point to understand is that `.setIn` uses the the index of whatever the underlying data type is. Since `list` is a `Immutable.List` we can use an integer to look up the first element, which is a `Immutable.Map`. The "index" of an `Immutable.Map` is the object `key`(string), which is why you can also do

`list = list.getIn([index, 'status'])` to get the status of an item.