# Changing one item in a list In immutable.js

Tags: javascript, redux, immutable.js

I'm using immutable.js, my data structure is like:

```
class ItemList extends Record({
    items: new List()
})
```

I want to write function that change one item in this list and keep other the same. For example, a list of {1, 2, 3, 4}, I need a function if an item equals 2, change it to 5.

I'm using something like

```
updateInfo(updatedInfo) {
    return this.withMutations(itemList => {
        itemList.set('items', list);
    });
}
```

My question is in this function, how can I just update one item? where should I put the if judgment?

Thanks!

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29589753/how-to-update-element-inside-list-with-immutablejs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NB: As mentioned by another answer, there is also the undocumented `indexOf` method which may be easier to use in some cases, taking only the value to find as parameter.

Using `findIndex` to find the index of the value you need to change and `set` with the index to change:

```
list = Immutable.List.of(1, 2, 3, 4);

list = list.set(list.findIndex(function(item) {
  return item === 2;
}), 5);
```

ES6:

```
list = list.set(list.findIndex((item) => item === 2), 5);
```

If you need the old value to change it, you can use `update` instead of set like:

```
list = list.update(list.findIndex(function(item) {
  return item === 2;
}), function(oldValue) {
  return 5;
});
```

ES6:

```
list = list.update(list.findIndex((item) => item === 2), (oldValue) => 5);
```

Comment: I somehow run into a error: list.set is not a function

Comment: @mlin956 you're most likely trying to use plain JS instead of the library Immutable.js https://immutable-js.com

Answer (score 6):

It is easy.

```
list = Immutable.List.of(1, 2, 3, 4);
list = list.set(list.indexOf(2), 5);

console.log(list.get(1));  //5
```

Answer (score 0):

A much cleaner version, based on forEach. Its a sideeffect (mutates an otherwise immutable list), so the syntax is similar to using a mutable list -

```
var list = Immutable.List.of(1, 2, 3, 4);

// Notice no LHS assignment is required as 
// forEach is a side-effect method.
list.forEach((value, index, theList) => {
    // You can check either value, or index
    if (index === soAndSo
        || value.something === something){

        // Just change the value!
        value.prop = someNewValue;

        // Or, in the above case where value
        // is not a reference
        theList.set(index) = newValue;

        // As we found and changed the value
        // of interest, lets exit forEach
        return false;
    }
});
```

And yes, there's a version for Map too.