# Update state where value = x in Redux/React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, lodash, normalizr

I have an array of users in my store set up like this:

```
{users: {user_id: 1, user_name: Adam, user_score: 100}, 
{user_id: 2, user_name: Bob, user_score: 200}, 
{user_id: 3, user_name: Charlie, user_score: 300}}
```

My project is receiving JSON data from the server that is set up like this:

```
{user_id: 1, score: 10}
```

I want to find where the `user_id` of the passed data matches the existing user set's `user_id` and update the score to the `score` that was passed in.

For example, if the reducer receives `{user_id:2, score:10}` how do I change the `score` to `10` where the user id equals `2` in the original state. While avoiding mutation, of course!

What would be the best way to use do this? Normalizr? Lodash? update()?
Seems pretty simple, I must be missing something obvious here.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `immutable.js` for this purpose.

Pass the `id` of the user which you want to update to the `action` and from there pass it to the `reducer` and use `immutable` to update the user data.

So you code in immutable would be something like

```
  const data = Immutable.fromJS(state)
  const newState = data.setIn(['users', user_id, 'score'], 10);
  return newState.toJS()
```

P.S: I havent tested the above but it should work(if not modify a little)

You can read about immutable [here](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/).

Also I would suggest going through a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29589753/how-to-update-element-inside-list-with-immutablejs)

Answer (score 1):

In your reducer, you can iterate through the existing users array and set a new value for the one that matches the `user_id`.

```
function usersReducer(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  case 'UPDATE_SCORE':
    var { user_id, score } = action
    return state.map(u => {
      if (u.user_id === user_id) {
        // for the matching user, return an
        // object with the updated score
        return Object.assign({}, u, { score })
      } else {
        // for all other users, return the
        // existing object
        return u
      }
    })
  default:
    return state
  }
}
```